# Mp3 file not converting to .wav using jlayer on linux but will on macOS

Tags: java, spring

I'm right now making a web server using spring boot to be able to upload and compare audio files. I'm using jlayer for the conversion to .wav as I'm using musicg for the comparison and it only takes .wav files.

The problem I have is that whenever I try converting .mp3 files to .wav files using linux, I only get the .mp3 file and not the converted .wav file. However when I try running the same program on my mac with the same repo and the same settings, same file, it shows me the .wav file. I'm trying to save it in a similar location as well and it still won't appear in linux.

Here is the method to save songs

```
public void saveSong(@NonNull MultipartFile song) {
        try {
            Path dir = Paths.get(songPath);
            if (!Files.exists(dir)) {
                createSongPath();
            }
            Files.copy(song.getInputStream(), dir.resolve(Objects.requireNonNull(song.getOriginalFilename())));
            Path songFilePath = Paths.get(songPath).resolve(song.getOriginalFilename());
            convertToWav(songFilePath.toString());
            FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(songFilePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Unable to save song: {}", song.getOriginalFilename());
        }
    }
```

And here is the convertToWav method if that helps as well

```
private void convertToWav(String fileName) {
        try {
            if (fileName.contains(".mp3")) {
                Converter converter = new Converter();
                converter.convert(fileName, songPath + "/song.wav");
            } else if (fileName.contains(".wav")) {
                logger.info("File contains .wav, not needed for conversion");
            }
        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to convert File: {}" , e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

I can provide the repo to anyone who needs it for testing, this is getting really frustrating and I really don't want to try using this on Windows 10 because I don't like using windows to code. I also can't always use my macbook.

Comment: Any exceptions thrown? Any log messages?

Comment: Sadly no, the .wav file isn't appearing in the folder it's supposed to be saved in